# How can I get my google maps to show 2+ polygon boundaries?

Tags: google-maps

I output to my page a list of polygon data to show as each separate shapes. This code below seems to only show the last polygon added to the map. I need to show all of them on the map at the same time.

The purpose is to show several shapes of zipcode blocks for a community and have an info window open with information about that community.

```
  var polysData = new Array();
  var oData = new Object();

  oData.CommunityID = '3';
  oData.geom = 'POLYGON ((-95.95255 40.392702, -95.952468 40.378206999999996, -95.95255 40.392702))';
  oData.ZipCode = '68305';
  polysData.push(oData);



  oData.CommunityID = '3';
  oData.geom = 'POLYGON ((-96.581603 40.045477999999996, -96.581777 40.045445, -96.581603 40.045477999999996))';
  oData.ZipCode = '68309';
  polysData.push(oData);



  oData.CommunityID = '3';
  oData.geom = 'POLYGON ((-96.066888999999989 40.494158, -96.066886 40.48666, -96.066885 40.48317, -96.066888999999989 40.494158))';
  oData.ZipCode = '68320';
  polysData.push(oData);

  var map;
  var infoWindow;
  var bounds ;
    function initMap() {
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var i; 
        var tmp;
           var myOptions = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.413467,-96.274233 ),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
                };
       var   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

       infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
       var col = '#FF000';
       for (i = 0; i < polysData.length; i++) {
          if (i == 1) col = '#00FF00';
          if (i == 2) col = '#0000FF';
          polysData[i].polys1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: parsePolyStrings(polysData[i].geom),
              strokeColor: '#000000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 1,
              fillColor: col,
              fillOpacity: 0.15,
              map: map
             });
          var n = polysData[i].ZipCode;

          google.maps.event.addListener(polysData[i].polys1, "click", function (event) {
              infoWindow.setContent("This CommunityID is: " +  n);
              infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
              infoWindow.open(map);
              });

         //      for (var i = 0; i < polysData[i].polys1.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
         //bounds.extend(polysData[i].polys1.getPath().getAt(i));
         //      }
         //map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }
    }

    function parsePolyStrings(ps) {
      var i, j, lat, lng, tmp, tmpArr,
      arr = [],
      //match '(' and ')' plus contents between them which contain anything other than '(' or ')'
      m = ps.match(/\([^\(\)]+\)/g);
      if (m !== null) {
         for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
           //match all numeric strings
           tmp = m[i].match(/-?\d+\.?\d*/g);
           if (tmp !== null) {
              //convert all the coordinate sets in tmp from strings to Numbers and convert to LatLng objects
             for (j = 0, tmpArr = []; j < tmp.length; j += 2) {
                lng = Number(tmp[j]);
                lat    = Number(tmp[j + 1]);
                tmpArr.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
             }
             arr.push(tmpArr);
          }
      }
   }
   //array of arrays of LatLng objects, or empty array
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: You only have one  `oData` object, you push it onto the `polysData` array 3 times, so when you process the array you get 3 identical polygons, all on top of each other (as they all have the last set of properties you set).  Create a new `Object` for each polygon, before setting its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I think stemmed mainly from the duff response given by the `parsePolyStrings` function. That function was returning the lat/lng in the order they appear in the strings within the source data whereas you need them in the opposite order. I added some new points to the input data so that you might more easily observe the addition of the polygons as they were hard to find as mere lines on the map - which begs the question~ Why use Polygons to display lines only, why not use a PolyLine?

If you modify the `parsePolyStrings` function to accept a 2nd argument - for the `bounds` - you can easily extend this latLngBounds so that later you can `fitBounds`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: </title>
        <style>
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            var map,infoWindow,bounds,tmp,col;
            var polygons=[];

            var polysData = [];
                polysData.push({
                    CommunityID:3,
                    geom:'POLYGON ((-95.95255 40.392702, -95.952468 40.378206999999996, -95.95255 40.392702))',
                    ZipCode:68305
                });
                polysData.push({
                    CommunityID:3,
                    geom:'POLYGON ((-96.581603 40.045477999999996, -96.581777 40.045445, -96.581603 40.045477999999996))',
                    ZipCode:68309
                });
                polysData.push({
                    CommunityID:3,
                    geom:'POLYGON ((-96.066888999999989 40.494158, -96.066886 40.48666, -96.066885 40.48317, -96.066888999999989 40.494158))',
                    ZipCode:68320
                });
                polysData.push({/* A clearly visible PolyGon.... */
                    CommunityID:404,
                    geom:'POLYGON((-96.178487 40.377587,-96.177056 40.273619,-96.013566 40.275108,-96.010930 40.379736))',
                    ZipCode:123456
                });
                polysData.push({/* An even more obvious PolyGon.... */
                    CommunityID:303,
                    geom:'POLYGON ((-96.742282 40.465339, -96.746756 40.265854, -96.561438  40.266753, -96.546101 40.285770,-96.467254  40.300979, -96.392446 40.363040, -96.389052 40.379546, -96.388333 40.465014))',
                    ZipCode:123456
                });


            /*
                The lat/lng in this were in the wrong order for use with given coordinates...
            */
            function parsePolyStrings(ps,b) {
                var i, j, lat, lng, tmp, tmpArr,latlng,
                    arr = [],
                    m = ps.match(/\([^\(\)]+\)/g);

                if (m !== null) {
                    for (i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                        tmp = m[i].match(/-?\d+\.?\d*/g);

                        if (tmp !== null) {
                            for (j = 0, tmpArr = []; j < tmp.length; j+=2) {
                                lng = parseFloat(tmp[j]);
                                lat = parseFloat(tmp[j + 1]);
                                latlng={ lat:lat, lng:lng };
                                tmpArr.push( latlng );
                                b.extend( latlng )
                            }
                            arr.push( tmpArr );
                        }
                    }
                }
                return arr;
            }




            function initMap(){
                var options = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 40.413467, -96.274233 ),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                polysData.forEach( ( obj, index )=>{
                    col = ( index % 2 == 0 )? '#00FF00' : '#0000FF';
                    var coordinates=parsePolyStrings( obj.geom, bounds );
                    var config={
                        paths:coordinates,
                        strokeColor:'#000000',
                        strokeOpacity:0.8,
                        strokeWeight:1,
                        fillColor:col,
                        fillOpacity:0.15,

                        /* add custom properties */
                        cid:obj.CommunityID,
                        zip:obj.ZipCode
                    };
                    var poly=new google.maps.Polygon( config );
                        poly.setMap( map );

                    google.maps.event.addListener( poly, 'click', function(event){
                        infoWindow.setContent( "This CommunityID is: " +  this.cid + "\nZipCode: " + this.zip );
                        infoWindow.setPosition( event.latLng );
                        infoWindow.open( map );
                    });

                    polygons.push( poly );
                })
                map.fitBounds( bounds );
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: RamRaider - this example fixed all 3 of my problems. The bounds, the infowindow containing each seperate data of the shapes (zipcodes), and the issue of showing multiple shapes. my data polygons was cropped from 500 data points to about 3-4 is why it was just a line.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped more than expected then... good luck with the rest of the project! I just noticed though - I meant for the `map.fitBounds()` to be outside of the `polysData.forEach` loop